# What converts a .PDF into raw PHP $pdf(..) commands which FPDF can use to create that PDF? Then my PHP can manipulate these $pdf values

Tags: fpdf

I'm asking here because when I tried googling for this information I just got ever more endless irrelavent pages of confusing junk (but contain my search terms hidden somewhere on the page taken out of context). This utility must exist because I even got a fake discussion forum site with fake users each 'agreeing' their willingness to enter their creditcard numbers in a 'software download link' which one of these faked users 'posted' in response to a 'question'. Clearly nothing more than a creditcard number harvesting site to intercept people like me googling for it.

So I've already designed the PDF layout with MS Word, I exported as PDF easy enough. Next step run this PDF through some script app or program (whatever is called) to generate the $pdf(..) items, so that FPDF can recreate that PDF. My PHP to alter odd text embedded in the $pdf(..) strings. Other than that I'm no more interested in what these $pdf(..) are and how they're written than I would be with any other raw printer control codes.
All I want to know is simple: What converts a .PDF into the $pdf(..) list, for FPDF to recreate that PDF again.

Comment: What makes you think such a utility exists?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.